# Locking screen while app is in foreground prevents background execution (Android)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have app that is droping BLE connection in background after 10 minutes.

Everything works fine when app is connected to Debbuger if the device is locked while the app is in foreground the connection will be dropped after 10 minutes, but if we disconnect it and lock the device while the app is in Foreground , the connection is not dropped after timeout.

Are there some restrictions to Background execution when device is locked? Why does it work when connected to Debbuger?

Comment: "Why does it work when connected to Debbuger" probably because the power cable's plugged in. A lot of devices don't go to sleep (even though the screen may be off) while charging.

Answer (score 1):

Use Service in Foreground to create strong connection, it's the best option.
But even Foreground service doesn't help if Battery saving mode enabled, or another battery optimization modes.
Yes, debugger prevent app from being killed by system, actually not debugger but ADB connection. Sometimes test your application without USB plugged.
Also use PowerManager.WakeLock in service, it helps.